# How to use an UIActionSheet within an if statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an `if` statement that is working fine, but I need to add a 2nd `if` statement inside of it and I can't seem to figure out how to get it right.

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)xButton {
    if([_hasUserTakenAPhoto  isEqual: @"YES"]) {
        _xButtonAfterPhotoTaken = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [_xButtonAfterPhotoTaken showInView:self.view];
        NSString *title = [_xButtonAfterPhotoTaken buttonTitleAtIndex:1];

        if(title isEqualToString:@"Delete") {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];
        }
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];
    }
}
```

I get errors when I add in the 2nd if statement of:

```
if(title isEqualToString:@"Delete") {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];
}
```

I have tried making the 2nd if statement an "else if" but then it will not let me access the NSString object called "title". Is there an easier way to do this, or should I just make title a global variable?

Comment: You have no brackets on title.

Comment: You need the NSString *title out of the body of the if statement.

Comment: @Maddy add your answer and I'll except it. This is what happens when you combine a novice AND lack of sleep thanks for the fast help.

Comment: @user3117509 I did't post a comment or answer. I simply cleaned up your question.

Comment: I don't understand what's going in that code. First create an action sheet, then extract it's title, and check if the title is equal to Delete? When is that condition not gonna be true? I think you should read on how to use an `UIAlertView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIActionSheet`s are not used that way:

```
- (IBAction)xButton:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if ([_hasUserTakenAPhoto isEqual:@"YES"])
    {
        _xButtonAfterPhotoTaken = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete Photo?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [_xButtonAfterPhotoTaken showInView:self.view];
    } 
    else
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Check if it's the correct action sheet and the delete button (the only one) has been selected.
    if (actionSheet == _xButtonAfterPhotoTaken && buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)actionSheetCancel:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    NSLog(@"Canceled");
}
```

You gotta understand that interface elements are not "instant", there's plenty of asynchrony going on. When presenting an `UIActionSheet` for instance, the thread doesn't wait for the user to answer yes or no, it keeps running.

That's why there's delegates, and blocks, you present the `UIActionSheet`, and with the delegate you say "I'll take care of it when the user actually clicks it".

You'd be wondering, why not just wait for it to select it? Main thread takes care of updating the interface, animations, and retrieving user input (touches, keyboard taps, etc) and even running `NSTimers` that are subscript to the main `NSRunLoop`. Stopping main thread would lock the interface.

Comment: First time ever using it. Started objective-c 2 months ago.

Comment: @user3117509 Okay, expanded my answer to make it more clear why things are this way.

Comment: Thank you. I can see now how far off I really was. I'm gonna go dig through the action sheet documentation some more. I thought it was much simpler.

Comment: Can I have a minute of your time to chat? Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
- (IBAction)xButton
{
    NSString *title;

    if ([_hasUserTakenAPhoto isEqual:@"YES"])
    {
        _xButtonAfterPhotoTaken = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [_xButtonAfterPhotoTaken showInView:self.view];

        title = [_xButtonAfterPhotoTaken buttonTitleAtIndex:1];

        if ([title isEqualToString:@"Delete"])
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];
    }
}
```